# Magento 2 - website is not loading full in my server how i can fix this

Tags: magento2, apache2, ubuntu

[image: Error image]

Magento 2 -  when access my domain it's print like above image

i run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

then i cleared cache but it's not working ...

how i can fix this???

Comment: Is it your local? Have you checked file permissions

Comment: try deploying static content for the specific locale you use as Magento will deploy just for `en_US` if unspecified. Example: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area frontend en_GB`

Comment: Also check your base url settings and https settings

Comment: where i can check the https settings

Comment: @Zankar how i run bin/magento setup-content:deploy --area  **what i can type this place**

Comment: @prabhakaran7 `--area` is either `frontend` or `adminhtml`. You have a problem on storefront so you use `frontend`. After this you may specify the locale (language) you use.
https and URL settings are on Stores > Configuration > General  > Web > Base URLs